# Cannot change the font size of <h1> within a component of react

Tags: reactjs, npm, components, font-size

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {   //state is what decribes our app
            robot: robot,
            searchfield: ''
        }
    } 

    onSearchChange = (event) =>  {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value })       
        console.log(this.state.robot);
    }  

    render() {
        const filteredRobots = this.state.robot.filter( robot => {
            return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()); 
            })
        return(
        <div className='tc'>
            <h1>ROBOFRIENDS</h1>
            <SearchBox searchChange={ this.onSearchChange } />
            <CardList robot = { filteredRobots }/>  
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to enlarge the font size of ROBOFRIENDS，I've tried to create another css file for editing h1 and also tried

```
<h1 className="style:{fontSize=3em}">ROBOFRIENDS</h1>
```

But they both don't work. However, when I tried to use the same method for changing the font color and background color, they work!
Looking for someone can help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add styles with `className` prop. you have two options:

- adding a `className` to the element and styling that className in css.
- or adding `style` property like this: `style={{ fontSize: '3em' }}`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second one:

```
style={{ fontSize: '3em' }}
```

Because like this you can pass variables to this.

But my favorite way is to use styled-components.
https://styled-components.com/

Check this out, this is a very clean way to style in react.js and reuse the stylings.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. I would recommend installing 'styled-components'.
I have included an example of how you could use it below:-

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledHeading = styled.h1`
    font-size: 3em;
`;


class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            robot: robot,
            searchfield: ''
        }
    } 

    onSearchChange = (event) =>  {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value })       
        console.log(this.state.robot);
    }  

    render() {
        const filteredRobots = this.state.robot.filter( robot => {
            return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()); 
            })
        return(
        <div className='tc'>
            <StyledHeading>ROBOFRIENDS</StyledHeading>
            <SearchBox searchChange={ this.onSearchChange } />
            <CardList robot = { filteredRobots }/>  
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```